# Automate running the runnable java jar using the shell script

Tags: java, linux, shell, automation

I am running a runnable java jar from the command prompt like this-

> java -jar CassandraLnP.jar config.properties
>   NUMBER_OF_THREADS:10 TOTAL_RUNNING_TIME:30 >
>   cassandra_read_prod_netflix_1.10.1.txt

So whenever I want to run the above jar, I usually go and run the above whole command from the above command prompt so it is a manual process currently for me.

Now I want to automate this thing using shell script so that I can pass those parameters from the shell script and then execute the above command continuously without making any changes from my side.

The thing that I wanted to configure is-

1. NUMBER_OF_THREADS
2. TOTAL_RUNNING_TIME
3. cassandra_read_prod_netflix_1.10.1.txt

The above third point is that it should keep on changing the file names for me automatically. Lets take an example-

Suppose for the first time I am running my program, then I will be running with this configuration-

`java -jar CassandraLnP.jar config.properties NUMBER_OF_THREADS:10 TOTAL_RUNNING_TIME:30 > cassandra_read_prod_netflix_1.10.1.txt`

And after the above program is finished, my shell script should start the same program again but this time it should be something like this with the file name got changed-

`java -jar CassandraLnP.jar config.properties NUMBER_OF_THREADS:10 TOTAL_RUNNING_TIME:30 > cassandra_read_prod_netflix_1.10.2.txt`

In the second case, if you see closely, file name got changed from `1.10.1 to 1.10.2`. And it will keep on running continuously like this without my modification.

And the third time it will be something like this-

`java -jar CassandraLnP.jar config.properties NUMBER_OF_THREADS:10 TOTAL_RUNNING_TIME:30 > cassandra_read_prod_netflix_1.10.3.txt`

Is it possible to do this thing using the shell script?

My machine OS from where I will be running my shell script-

```
rkost@phx7b:~$ uname -a
Linux phx7b 2.6.35-22-server #33-Ubuntu SMP Sun Sep 19 20:48:58 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: So, your script should form the command first and execute it. Everything else looks constant, except for the file name. You can make the script save the variable part in your file name to a file a file (or somewhere), which it can use in the next run.

Comment: Yeah that's what I need to do I guess. Can you provide an example how to do that as I am not much comfortable in shell scripting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like this ?

```
#!/bin/sh

for ((i=0; i<3; i++))
  do
    java -jar CassandraClientReadLnP.jar config.properties NUMBER_OF_THREADS:10 TOTAL_RUNNING_TIME:30 > cassandra_read_prod_netflix_1.10.$i.txt
  done
```